# Differential Equation and Matlab

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, matlab

Hello I am currently trying to solve a differential equation using Matlab; however, my problem is not with the code but the math.  I have achieved at an answer to this question 252.0178 m/s.  That is the escape velocity at burnout.

I have assumed the task with my limited knowledge by first me solving the math, then programming.  I started by finding out the acceleration equation from the Force equation.

### Background of the equation

$m(t)=m_0(1-rt/b)$

$T=48,000$ Newtons

$m_0=2200$ kg

$r=0.8$

$a=9.81$ m/$s^2$

$b=40$ sec.

$$m(t)*\frac{dv}{dt}=T-m(t)g$$
therefore, to get the acceleration equation we divide by the mass

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{T-m(t)*g}{m(t)}$$

Now doing some basic math I noticed I could cancel out the $m(t)$ by dividing out the function.

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{T}{m(t)}-g$$

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{24}{11(1-\frac{.8t}{40})}-9.81$$
and the function is not defined where $m(t)=0$.

I believe that burnout occurs when the acceleration of the rocket is equal to zero.  So I then integrated and achieved

$$v(t)= -9.81 t - 109.091 \log(50 - t)+C$$

But C is zero because the initial velocity is zero since the rocket is at rest.
And then I plugged the zero of the acceleration function which is $t=36.88$

And I achieved a negative answer -642.608.

However when I changed g back to negative since its pulling the rocket down, and reintergrated the acceleration function, therefore, I got 80.9775

I believe it should be positive since it is going up escaping Earth.

This the beginning of the Matlab code I am just wondering if the quad command should be used since it only does numerical integration.

```
>> T=48000
```

T =  48000

> > mo=2200
> >     mo =  2200
> >     r=0.8
> >     r =  0.80000
> >     g=9.81
> >     g =  9.8100
> >     b=40
> >     b =  40
> >     function y =M(t)
> >     y=mo.*(1-(r.*t)/b);
> >     end
> >     function w = A(t)
> >     w= (4800/M(t))-9.81;
> >     endtext here

Comment: Why do you think that $v(0)=0$ implies $C=0$?

Comment: @Eddy Point taken doesn't it start at rest?  Because its a rocket lifting off the instantaneous velocity should be 0 at lift off?

Comment: If your rocker starts at rest that's fine, but then $C\neq 0$

Comment: @Eddy So I can go with zero in my problem because it's not aforementioned whether or not it has a non-zero initial velocity at t=0.  THe problem is I not an expert in calculus, and my buddy is helping me and he keeps mentioning that the constant of the integrad matters because then the velocity at a certain point could be different if it weren't zero.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you don't know what problem your trying to solve. If your rocket is already moving really fast before it starts burning fuel then when it's finished burning fuel it will be going even faster. Is that what you want? You can't 'choose C', you can only choose the initial speed of the rocket.

Comment: Yes you're right have to plug in 0 into the solution of the integral to get C.

Comment: If you follow what @Eddy is trying to say is use $t=0$ in your equation for $v$. Then  $C$ is definitely not $0$. It is $109.091\log(50)$